# Pushpin tap event error in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

```
private void Pushpin_Tap(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var _ppmodel = sender as Pushpin;
        ContextMenu contextMenu = 
            ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(_ppmodel);
        contextMenu.DataContext = _viewModel.Pushpins.Where
            (c => (c.Location 
                == _ppmodel.Location)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
        {
            contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Here in where condition i am getting error like "no definition for it".please tell me

Comment: what is the error you are getting? on what line is it happening?

Comment: contextMenu.DataContext = _viewModel.Pushpins.Where
            (c => (c.Location 
                == _ppmodel.Location)).FirstOrDefault();in where condition.

Comment: And what is the error? Message and/or stacktrace?

Comment: doen't contain a definition for 'where' and no extension method 'where'accepting first argument of type system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection<pushpinmodel>could not fpund.

Comment: You need to add a using statement for System.Linq

Comment: Thanks got it.how to add map zoom level,center the map  in that?map.zoomlevel=15;i given but not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have the correct using statements in the file

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: using the sample from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229125 I added a loaded event and set zoomlevel and it worked fine